# Horizontal Scroll menu

Tags: jquery, прокрутка, if

Нужно зделать прокручеваное горизонтальное меню:

```
this.$el.on('wheel', (e) => {
      this.headerOffsetX = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta + this.headerOffsetX;
      this.$el.stop().animate({
        'margin-left': this.headerOffsetX,
        }, 1);
      //console.log(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta);
      e.preventDefault();
    })
```

Не могу зделать проверку для ограничения, что бы елементы прокручивались до определьоного мемента.

Answer (score 0):

```
e.preventDefault();
this.headerOffsetX = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta + this.headerOffsetX;
var maximum = 1500; // ваш определенный момент в px

if(this.headerOffsetX > maximum) return;
```

Если this.headerOffsetX больше определенного значения, код ниже условия (if) выполнятся не будет.